# Having trouble with positioning the Lightbox2 close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox2

I'm trying to customize the placement of a close button for lightbox2 and I could use your help.

Currently, my close button appears *over* the lightbox image in the upper right as shown in my example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/xyzerb/pen/zryvmJ.

I need for the close button to appear *on top of* the image in the upper right as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4mVn.png.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to programming, but I didn't expect this part to be challenging.

Thank you in advance. Please let me know if there's anything that I can do to help you in return.

**Please Ignore the Following Comment**

`/*! The system requires inclusion of a line of code if you link to CodePen, so I'm adding a comment. Please ignore. */`

Comment: Invalid Codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
.lb-data .lb-close {
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: In which version does this work? Doesn't work in Lightbox v2.11.3

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this by using css. Below css code will help you to fix.

```
.lb-dataContainer{ position:relative; }
.lb-closeContainer{ position: absolute; right: -11px; top: -8px; z-index: 11; }
```

Comment: In which version does this work? Doesn't work in Lightbox v2.11.3

Answer (score 0):

This is not the actual solution for Lightbox v2.11.3 but it works.

```
.lightbox{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

as it just reverse the column order.